# VS adding service reference to connected services folder

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to add a service reference to my .net framework library project. The project is targeting 4.5.1 .net framework. When I add the service reference vs creates a "Connected Services" folder and places the service reference under this folder. I expected this to be under a folder named "Service References". Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why the location bothers you?

Comment: After playing with it for a while I will have to say no I'll suck it up. My initial concern was what kind of effect I could encounter down the road if any. Also all of our (The company) projects services are under "Service References" so I didn't want to get away from that.

Comment: any solution , please?